# loopback returns unchanged document when using updateAttributes() on extended user model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

calling `updateAttributes` on my extended user-model 'user' succeeds, returns updated document, updates the database but if i query the exact same document it remains unchanged:
(called in a remote method)

```
models.user.findById(userId, function (err, userInstance) {

    console.log(userInstance)

    let newAttributes = {
        firstName:"Test"
    }

    userInstance.updateAttributes(newAttributes, function (err, newInstance) {

        console.log(newInstance)

        models.user.findById(userId, function (err, notUpdatedUser) {

        console.log(notUpdatedUser)
        });
    });
});
```

- the first log prints my user with firstName: 'Original'
- the second log prints my correctly updated user with firstName 'Test'
- the third log prints the same as the first.

**Additionally the database changes correctly!**
When i check my entries in my datasource the updateAttributes is reflected correctly and in the end i have no idea where the old data comes from.

Any hints what might be the underlying problem here? I suspect the extended user model but have nowhere to begin digging

Comment: Sounds like mongodb is just taking a while to "commit" the update changes, you can test this by waiting a few milliseconds and then querying the updated model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loopback3 (not sure about loopback2) this behavior depend on `updateOnLoad` option. You can find some informatin here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html

> By default, create and updateAttributes do not apply database updates
>   to the model instance returned to the callback, therefore any changes
>   made by “loaded” hooks are discarded. To change this behavior, set a
>   per-model option updateOnLoad: true.